# How do I bind an inline style?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've been following the guide: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles for inline css in VueJS. However in some situations, it not working.

> :style="{ background: colorSelected }"  // working

The following gives an error saying: - invalid expression: :style="{ border-color-left: colorSelected }"

> :style="{ border-color-left: colorSelected }"  // not working

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's invalid JavaScript syntax for an object literal. The object property needs to have quotes:

```
:style="{ 'border-left-color': colorSelected }"
```

or you can specify it like this (Vue-specific):

```
:style="{ borderLeftColor: colorSelected }"
```

Also the style is `border-left-color` not `border-color-left`.

Comment: Great. Thanks!  Actually I've tried this. But didn't work. Because I was using border-color-left instead of border-left-color